# Flex/Actionscript code highlighter

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, syntax-highlighting

On an opensource project that im working on we need to do some codehighlighting in a flexapplication.

So my question is whether there exist such a project already or if know of a good library suitable for porting to action script.

Or should we perhaps generate html that we display in text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript and Actionscript are pretty close languages so you should be able to take a javascript library and customize it.

I did a quick search on google for [javascript code highlighter](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=javascript+code+highlighter&aq=0&oq=javascript+code+high&aqi=g2) and there are a few worth looking at. A search for [actionscript code highlighter library](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=actionscript+code+highlighter+library&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) comes up with a few as well including a google code project [as3syntaxhighlight](http://code.google.com/p/as3syntaxhighlight/).

Comment: That doesn't really hold true anymore.  AS3 is quite different from javascript now.

Comment: I said *pretty* close ;) -- someone with a decent understanding should be able to do a port with little effort.